# Replacing asterisks (*) in a text with SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

A common way to mark required fields in an HTML form is to simply append an asterisk (*) to it, and (maybe) a paragraph at the top or bottom of the form explaining the asterisk:

```
<label for="name">Name *</label>
<input type="text" id="name">

<p>* Required field</p>
```

I need to replace the text asterisk with an SVG graphic:

- I need it as inline SVG directly in the HTML code (no external resource)
- I need it re-usable

My first approach is this:

https://codepen.io/accessibility-developer-guide/pen/zEYKVR

I'm quite new to SVG, so I have the following problems:

- How should I add the `<svg>` container with the definition in it? Is CSS `display: none` the correct way?
- How can I scale the SVG "naturally" so it fits the size of the text? I played around with `width` and `height`, but this crops the SVG container size and doesn't scale its contents.

Maybe there's an even more effective way to attach the asterisk to the texts, e.g. using CSS as `background-image` on the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements?

Comment: An SVG seems like overkill, when you could use a pseudo element with the `content`"*"` and scale it using `font size:1em`

Comment: I know about this solution, but `content` is read by screen readers, which I don't want.

Comment: In that even, you need to use a proper `viewbox` in your SVG, then wrap your use an a span and scale it appropiately..at least at first blush.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want like this.

```css
.control {
  margin: 6px 0;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.st0{
 fill:#ff0000;
}
.ast {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"style="display:none;">
<defs>
  <symbol id="asterisk" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
  <g>
    <path class="st0" d="M110.1,16.4L75.8,56.8l0.3,1l50.6-10.2v32.2l-50.9-8.9l-0.3,1l34.7,39.1l-28.3,16.5L63.7,78.2L63,78.5   l-18.5,49L17.2,111l34.1-39.8v-0.6l-50,9.2V47.6l49.3,9.9l0.3-0.6L17.2,16.7L45.5,0.5l17.8,48.7H64L82.1,0.5L110.1,16.4z"/>
  </g>
  </symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
<form>
  <div class="control">
    <label for="name">Full name <svg class="ast"><use xlink:href="#asterisk"></use></svg>     
    </label>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <label for="biography">Biography</label><textarea id="biography" type="text"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
  </div>
  <p aria-hidden="true"> 
  <svg class="ast"><use xlink:href="#asterisk"></use></svg> Required field
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: This looks also very promising. Same question like the other answer: Is there a way to move it into a CSS `background-image` of a `label::after` pseudo element? So I don't need to have a full `<svg>` tag for every occurrence of an asterisk?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I scale the SVG "naturally" so it fits the size of the text?

You need to give your SVG a `viewBox` to tell the browser the dimensions of the SVG. Otherwise it has no idea how much it needs to scale it.

Your SVG path is approx 23x25. So your viewBox should be something like `"0 0 23 25"`.

```
svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 23 25"
    use xlink:href="#asterisk"
```

> How should I add the  container with the definition in it? Is CSS display: none the correct way?

Using `width="0" height="0"` is usually better. `display:none` can cause problems in some cases.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGYxmE

Comment: This looks very promising. Is there a way to move it into a CSS `background-image` of a `label::after` pseudo element? So I don't need to have a full `<svg>` tag for every occurrence of an asterisk?

Comment: Yes. You can include it as a Data URI.